# Using MacPorts within FISH shell

Tags: macos, terminal.app, macports, fish

I have been playing around with FISH for a few days and I just tried to switch it to my main shell. That worked fine but now none of my software from MacPorts is recognized.

I installed and followed the advice from http://ridiculousfish.com/shell/faq.html, using the package installer form here http://ridiculousfish.com/shell/.

The python script made this entry from my .profile to my config.fish file

```
set_default export PATH "/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
```

but I get this error

> fish: Unknown command 'set_default'
>   /Users/ley/.config/fish/config.fish (line 1): set_default export PATH "/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
>                                                 ^
>   in . (source) call of file '/Users/ley/.config/fish/config.fish',
>       called on standard input,

I fiddled with the set command a bit but that didn't seem to help much.

Any advice?

Comment: Please take this in a spirit of helpfulness, but if I were you, I'd take this as a sign that I'm not ready to commit to switching to this shell yet. Getting one's PATH set up right is like the "hello world" of shell usage.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you want:

```
set -xg PATH /opt/local/bin /opt/local/sbin $PATH
```

**Edit:** *I see what you mean, this syntax takes some getting used to. It wants spaces instead of colons, and it can't be in quotes, and all the paths in your current PATH must actually exist (in my case, I had `/usr/local/sbin` in my PATH even though it didn't actually exist, and that was a problem for `fish`).*

Comment: @Ley If you read my Answer previously, please read it again now that I've edited it a couple times to fix some syntax errors.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Still getting the hang of it seems like it's filled with good ideas so far just been using bash forever and a half.

Comment: Now I need to do this everytime I open up a new tab, is there a way to automatically do this?

Comment: @Jan-WillemdeBoer It should go in your config.fish file.